# PHPDoc: How to hide private properties and methods

Tags: phpdoc

The documentation just shows that an xml configuration property exists for visibility, but doesn't show how to use it.  The documentation for the [command line equivalent](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/commands/project_run.html#usage) shows:

```
–visibility[=”...”]
Provide a comma-separated list of visibility scopes to parse.

This parameter may be used to tell phpDocumentor to only parse public properties and methods, or public and protected.
```

There are private properties that are showing up in my documentation and I'd like to hide them.  I've tried `<visibility>public</visibility>` but it appears to have no effect.

**Update**

I'm currently using the default template.  It both lists the private methods and shows a "Private Methods" section on the template.

Answer (score 0):

If that --visibility flag is not working, it must be a bug.  Then again, it's possible that some output templates display the three visibility view toggles even if the document generation execution was run with only "public" being enabled.

In the resulting docs you've generated with a particular template, are you still seeing all three visibility buttons showing?  If so, enable the private and protected buttons, then see if any private/protected properties/methods actually do become visible.  It might be that you are getting only public things documented, but just still seeing the private/protected toggle buttons in the view.

Comment: All 3 buttons/sections show, and it also lists private properties.

Comment: Must be a bug with the --visibility runtime flag then.  I figured the buttons would probably be there regardless, but that no code elements would show up if the buttons were enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me **--visibility="public"**

Answer (score 0):

The visibility element works. Put inside

```
 <parser>
    <visibility>public</visibility>
    <target>docs/api</target>
</parser>
```